# AWS Lambda Template doesn't see my own bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I was following this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/serverless-image-handler/deployment.html) to deploy my Lambda. The solution used their own `.template` file to deploy it. However, I needed to make some code changes to that Lambda, so I uploaded my changed Lambda code to my own bucket, and changed the `.template` to work with my own bucket.

**The original template**

```
CustomResource:
      S3Bucket: solutions
      S3Key: >-
        serverless-image-handler/v3.0.0/serverless-image-handler-custom-resource.zip
      Name: serverless-image-handler-custom-resource
      Handler: image_handler_custom_resource/cfn_custom_resource.lambda_handler
      Description: >-
        Serverless Image Handler: CloudFormation custom resource function
        invoked during CloudFormation create, update, and delete stack
        operations.
      Runtime: python2.7
      Timeout: '60'
      MemorySize: '128'
```

**My Customized Template (uses my bucket)**

```
CustomResource:
      S3Bucket: my-bucket
      S3Key: >-
        serverless-image-handler/serverless-image-handler-custom-resource.zip
      Name: serverless-image-handler-custom-resource
      Handler: image_handler_custom_resource/cfn_custom_resource.lambda_handler
      Description: >-
        Serverless Image Handler: CloudFormation custom resource function
        invoked during CloudFormation create, update, and delete stack
        operations.
      Runtime: python2.7
      Timeout: '60'
      MemorySize: '128'
```

Of course, in my bucket I put the package under the correct path `serverless-image-handler/serverless-image-handler-custom-resource.zip`. However, when trying to deploy, I'm getting the following error.

```
Error occurred while GetObject. S3 Error Code: NoSuchBucket. S3 Error Message: The specified bucket does not exist (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: 6b666b56-dc62-11e8-acb0-8df0d82e071b)
```

It's like it can't "see" my own bucket, but it sees the bucket `solutions`. How can I make it see my bucket?

**EDIT**

Part of the template where the bucket is defined.

```
Parameters:
  OriginS3Bucket:
    Description: S3 bucket that will source your images.
    Default: original-images-bucket-name
    Type: String
    ConstraintDescription: Must be a valid S3 Bucket.
    MinLength: '1'
    MaxLength: '64'
    AllowedPattern: '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-.]*'
  OriginS3BucketRegion:
    Description: S3 bucket Region that will source your images.
    Default: eu-central-1
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - ap-south-1
      - ap-northeast-1
      - ap-northeast-2
      - ap-southeast-1
      - ap-southeast-2
      - ca-central-1
      - eu-central-1
      - eu-west-1
      - eu-west-2
      - eu-west-3
      - sa-east-1
      - us-east-1
      - us-east-2
      - us-west-1
      - us-west-2
```

Part of the template that threw an error.

```
CustomResource:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    DependsOn:
      - CustomResourceLoggingPolicy
      - CustomResourceDeployPolicy
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Join
          - ''
          - - !FindInMap
              - Function
              - CustomResource
              - S3Bucket
            - '-'
            - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        S3Key: !FindInMap
          - Function
          - CustomResource
          - S3Key
      MemorySize: !FindInMap
        - Function
        - CustomResource
        - MemorySize
      Handler: !FindInMap
        - Function
        - CustomResource
        - Handler
      Role: !GetAtt
        - CustomResourceRole
        - Arn
      Timeout: !FindInMap
        - Function
        - CustomResource
        - Timeout
      Runtime: !FindInMap
        - Function
        - CustomResource
        - Runtime
      Description: !FindInMap
        - Function
        - CustomResource
        - Description
      Environment:
        Variables:
          LOG_LEVEL: INFO
```

Comment: Maybe your bucket is within another AWS region? According to the template from the link supplided, it defaults to `us-east-1`.

Comment: @Peba I set up the region to match the region where my bucket it. It's possible to do in the UI just before deploying the template as an environment variable, but I also hardcoded my own region into the template. None of those worked. Please see my edit.